# Paraphrasing whole paragraphs with Pegasus

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface

I've been trying to use Pegasus to paraphrase things, so far it does paraphrases sentences nicely, but the issue is, that it actually takes a part of the paragraph, usually the last part and rephrases it instead of the whole given "phrase", which is the provided paragraph.
I would like it to paraphrase the whole given paragraph.

My function to do so:

```
from transformers import *


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase")
        self.tokenizer = PegasusTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase")


    
    def get_paraphrased_sentences1(self, model, tokenizer, sentence, num_return_sequences=5, num_beams=5):
        # tokenize the text to be form of a list of token IDs
        inputs = tokenizer([sentence], truncation=True, padding="longest", return_tensors="pt")
        # generate the paraphrased sentences
        outputs = model.generate(
            **inputs,
            max_length=8096,
            length_penalty=2.0,
            num_beams=num_beams,
            num_return_sequences=num_return_sequences,
        )
        # decode the generated sentences using the tokenizer to get them back to text
        return tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

If we're to take an example:
Original input:

```
Randal went to the mall to get some clothes. When he got home he found his wife cheating on him. Randal ended up kicking her out of the house. The kids stay with Randal and not the cheating wife.
```

Received output sequences:

```
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, so he kicked her out of the house and the kids stayed with him.
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, so he kicked her out of the house and put the kids with him.
When he returned from the mall, he found his wife cheating on him and he kicked her out of the house and the kids stayed with him.
When he returned from the mall, he found his wife cheating on him and he kicked her out of the house.
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, so he kicked her out of the house and the children stayed with him.
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, and he kicked her out of the house.
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, so he kicked her out of the house and put the kids in his care.
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, so he kicked her out of the house.
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, so he kicked her out of the house and kept the kids with him.
When he got home, he found his wife cheating on him, so he kicked her out of the house and put his kids with him.
```

That's basically the issue I've been working on for the past few days, I've looked through the [Pegasus Documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.21.2/en/model_doc/pegasus#transformers.PegasusForConditionalGeneration) to check if there are any parameters that may fix this, but found nothing that worked, I've tried a few, among them was max_length and min_length and that didn't work.